# WebApi Odata: remove metadata from response

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an WebApi Odata service for internal usage. I want to remove from response at server all additional data except serialized data. 
I want to remove all this stuff:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://192.168.150.86:9933/odata/$metadata#Terminal","value":[

  ]
}
```

and leave here only array of "Terminal"

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following option to your query string:

```
$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none
```

This will remove the odata metadata from your results.

Comment: It did not work. I tried in postman using Content-type  header and also tried as Accept header but non of these worked for me.

Comment: @IshworKhanal It should be added to your URL query string and not the headers.
Here's how it should look:
`example.com/myapi?$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none`

Comment: It works for me both if I add it as an OData querystring instruction as shown in this answer, but it also works if I use Fiddler to send the request with the following request header:

Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none

Both give the same result: the @odata.context line is not included in the response.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be accomplished.

```
var ODataJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
ODataJSON.Property("@odata.context").Remove();
ODataJSON.Add("Terminal", ODataJSON["value"]); //adding Terminal attribute
ODataJSON.Property("value").Remove(); // removing default value attribute.
```

Comment: i need to remove it from response on server side, not at client

Comment: initial question didn't specify that, but to my knowledge this cannot be deleted, this is what odata by default returns

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the `Accept` header

```
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you are writing a new function that returns IHttpActionResult. To return the data you can use the Json method. It removes the metadata